# Amend Macro to copy data from worksheets with different names

Tags: excel, vba

The issue i have is that the workbook will have many versions. e.g Prom Code Grid V43 etc. How can I amend the code so the sheet is copied regardless of the name of the workbook?

```
Windows("Prom Code Grid V42.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Prom Code Loading").Select
Sheets("Prom Code Loading").Copy Before:=Workbooks("gridload.xlsm").Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to explain how to *identify* which sheet should be copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of the workbook will always be the same and only the version will change, you can loop through all the open workbooks you have and check only for "Prom Code Grid" in the name ignoring the version.

```
    Sub get_Prom_Code 

Dim Prom_WK as Workbook 
For Each wk in Application.Workbooks 
  If Instr(1, wk.name, "Prom Code Grid") > 0 Then 
    Set Prom_WK = wk 
  End if 
Next wk 

Prom_WK.Activate
Prom_WK.Sheets("Prom Code Loading").Copy Before:=Workbooks("gridload.xlsm").Sheets(1) End Sub
```